# Chrome/Safari blur function support checking in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, blur

I'm trying to detect when a file upload input field has been updated. 
In IE & FF I can do this if I use blur() but for Chrome I need to use change().
Since Chrome (and I believe safari) don't trigger the blur event is there a property in the jquery.supports object to check for this or do I have to use the deprecated .browser object?

Here's a sample page that shows what I mean, as the poster below says the changed event works on all three browsers and is what I should be using but I think it's still useful to get an answer to the question of detecting support for the blur event.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test-input').change(function () { alert('changed'); });
            $('#test-input').blur(function () { alert('blurred'); });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="test-input">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These browsers trigger the event properly...do you have an example that demonstrates the issue?  `.change()` should work in all browsers for what you're after.

Comment: You're right, when I tried to create a simple demo the change event was triggered in all three browsers. I suspect I may have a problem with my code. However having said that although FF & IE triggered the blur event when clicking away chrome didn't. So I'm posting the code anyway to see if a) there's a problem with my code or b) if there's a way to detect support/non-support for the feature/bug.

Comment: `change()` worked in all browsers. If you worried that `change()` is not triggered again when user select the same file again, do `$('form')[0].reset()`

Comment: That's fine, just out of curiosity I'd still like to know if it's possible to detect non/partial support for the blur event through jquery without specifying the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try dectecting if your event is supported using this function which I cannot take credit for, however I forgot where I got it:

```
var isEventSupported = function(eventName) { //Function to detect supported events
var el = document.createElement('div');
    eventName = 'on' + eventName;
    var isSupported = (eventName in el);
    if (!isSupported) {
        el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
        isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
        }
    el = null;
    return isSupported;
    }
```

After that define a variable that will contain your either/or event:

```
var ChangeOrBlur = (isEventSupported('blur')) ? 'blur' : 'change'; //with change as your default
```

Then bind your function to whatever your prefrered event is:

```
$('#test-input').bind(ChangeOrBlur, function(){alert(ChangeOrBlur);});
```

Let me know how that works our for you...